# Custom description page for the WCF endpoint?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, metadata

I am migrating an ASP.NET Web Service toward WCF. The *old* Web Service endpoint had a nice extensive description page generated from the comment of the underlying class exposed as a service endpoint. In particular, all available web methods were listed.

Is there a way to emulate somehow this behavior with WCF? At least, how can I customize the HTML content of the WCF endpoint?

Comment: this may help http://cgeers.com/2011/09/04/replacing-the-you-have-created-a-service-message/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no, there's no way to change that right now.

From what I've heard and read, there will be a customizable "help page" mechanism in WCF 4 - but as far as I know, only for REST-based services (which don't have the help of a WSDL/XSD).

Check this out: [WCF Web Programming Help Page](http://blogs.msdn.com/nathana/archive/2007/09/17/wcf-web-programming-help-page.aspx)

For the SOAP based services: you can always define your own custom URL where you drop your WSDL/XSD that should be retrieved by clients, but that's just that - a WSDL that describes your service. You can of course add WSDL comments to your document to explain a bit, but it's still quite limited.

I don't think there's any "out-of-the-box" provision in WCF to support manipulating / customizing the actual service page that gets rendered back to the client. Or if there is: I'd love to know about it!